# How to write a simple sub in perl that takes a string and returns a string?

Tags: perl, programming-languages

```
sub getHeading
{
    my $var = $_[0];
    my $match;
     if ($match = ($var =~ m/$fivetonine/))
     {
        return "=";
     }
     if ($match = ($var =~ m/$tentofourteen/))
     {
        return "==";
     }
     if ($match = ($var =~ m/$fifteentonineteen/)){
        return "===";
     }
     return "===";
}
my $ref_to_getHeading = \getHeading;
```

and I am calling it via:

```
$html =~ s/(.*)<font size="([^"]+)">(.+)<\/font>(.*)/$ref_to_getHeading($2)$1$3$4$ref_to_getHeading($2)/m;
```

I am wanting to pass a string in to this function, I want to check if it is one of 3 different matches and return the appropriate number of = signs, I am doing this wrong but I can't figure out how to make it take parameters? I get a run time error saying $var is initialised? I tried using @_ but I don't really understand what the difference is.

Any help much appreciated, I have never written perl before and this is my first real program.

Comment: As for using @_, elements inside that array are aliases for the parameters you passed in, so that changes to the elements of @_ will reflect on the originals. For instance,
sub marine { chomp $_[0]; return $_[0] } my $test_string = "Hello!\n"; marine($test_string); say "[$test_string]"; Will chomp off the newline from $test_string - And will promptly die if you pass a constant, ala marine("Boom!\n"); So long as your sub doesn't modify it's parameters, using @_ directly or copying it to another variable are practically the same. Well, readability aside.

Comment: `$match =` is completely useless and can be removed in all the ifs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double mistake there.

First, you aren't taking a reference to a function - You need to add the ampersand.

But even if you do that, it won't work. You are missing the /e flag in your substitution: You can't dereference a coderef within a string like you'd normally do with (scalar|hash|array)ref:

```
my $example = sub { return "hello" };
say "$example->()"; #Will stringify the coderef.
```

You either need the /e flag,

```
$html =~ s/etc/$ref_to_getHeading->($2) . "$1$3$4" . $ref_to_getHeading->($2)/em;
```

Or a little trick:

```
$html =~ s/etc/@{[$ref_to_getHeading->($2)]}$1$3$4@{[$ref_to_getHeading->($2)]}/m;
```

EDIT: Gosh, am I a slow typist..
Anyhow, with either way, you should be able to call the sub directly, so no need for the coderef.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the reply! Perl has so many little tricks and things to learn, I imagine it will be some time before I get to learn them all, that and this will probably the the first and last program I get to write in it for some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The line `my $ref_to_getHeading = \getHeading;` doesn't do what you think it does.  To take a reference to a subroutine:

```
my $ref_to_getHeading = \&getHeading;  # note the &
```

So you were actually calling `getHeading` and storing the result. Since you passed no arguments, you got the undefined value warning.

The substitution however will never call the coderef, for that to happen, you need to add the `e` modifier to run the replacement text through eval:

```
$html =~ s/.../join '' => getHeading($2), $1, $3, $4, getHeading($2)/me;
```

you may run into issues here with `getHeading` resetting the match vars too early.  In which case, try writing it this way:

```
$html =~ s{...}{
    my $body = $1 . $3 . $4;
    my $heading = getHeading($2);
    $heading . $body . $heading
}me;
```

The bracket change for `s///` was not necessary, I just find it easier to read a multi-line curly block.

Comment: Ah thank you, is there any simple way to just call the sub directly without the reference? as $getHeading($2)$1$3$4$getHeading($2) doesn't work.

Comment: Also the function now just makes my string this: CODE(0x23bb8a4)(7.5pt)Last modified by Phil BathCODE(0x23bb8a4)(7.5pt), so I am not returning the argument correctly either, what am I doing wrong? thanks for the help :)

Comment: @rolls => in the examples of the substitution I have above, I am not even using `$ref_to_getHeading` since it is not necessary.  I have a feeling you decided to take the reference and then use that in the string hoping that it would interpolate.  Perl will never interpolate a subroutine call in a string, even if the subroutine is held in a scalar.  The output you are getting is the stringified coderef, followed by `(7.5pt)` which was `($1)` before interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for the additions to your reply, very helpful! didn't know you could do multiline matches like that, great hint.